# how to create a enum associated with value and provided parametrize a enum in one of case in swift

Tags: swift

I would like to create a enum associated with value and provided parametrize a enum in one of case. How can I do it?

the logic is for case `good` return `good`, case `bad` return `bad`, case `other` if no argument provided default value "unknown" is associated. if any argument provided, use the argument

I use first part snippet but get error `error: enum with raw type cannot have cases with arguments`

part 2 code seems ok but any other way to make the code cleaner? I do not want to use enum.string to get the value

```
// Part 1
public enum Status: String {
    case good
    case bad
    case other(s: String? = "unknown")
}
let good = Status.good // good
let bad = Status.bad //bad
let unknown = Status.other() //unknown
let knownA = Status.other(s: "up") // up
let knownB = Status.other(s: "down") // down
```

```
// Part 2
enum StatusA {
 case other(String = "unknown")
 case good, bad

 var string: String {
   switch self {
   case .good:
     return "good"
   case .bad:
     return "bad"
   case .other(let s):
     return s
   }
 }
}

let good = StatusA.good // good
let bad = StatusA.bad //bad
let unknown = StatusA.other() //unknown
let knownA = StatusA.other("up") // up
let knownB = StatusA.other("down") // down

// value is expected but it is not what I want
print("\(good)") // good
print("\(bad)") // bad
print("\(unknown)") // other("unknown")
print("\(knownA)") // other("up")
print("\(knownB)") // other("down")


// value is expected but I do not want to use case.string
print("\(good.string)") // good
print("\(bad.string)") // bad
print("\(unknown.string)") // unknown
print("\(knownA.string)") // up
print("\(knownB.string)") // down
```

Comment: "I do not want to use enum.string to get the value" How *do* you want to get the value then? If it's just for `print` and string interpolation, how about conform to `CustomStingConvertible`?

Comment: "but it is not what I want" What _do_ you want instead?

Comment: I want `let good = StatusA.good print(good) // good`

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to see the "associated string" when you `print` it, or when it is in an interpolated string, you can just conform to `CustomStringConvertible`, since that is one of the protocols `print` and `String` interpolation looks for.

```
extension StatusA: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        string
    }
}
```

If you also want a `RawRepresentable` conformance, similar to the one you get by doing `enum StatusA: String`, you can conform to that explicitly too:

```
enum StatusA: RawRepresentable, CustomStringConvertible {
    case other(String = "unknown")
    case good, bad
    
    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .good:
            return "good"
        case .bad:
            return "bad"
        case .other(let s):
            return s
        }
    }
    
    init(rawValue: String) {
        switch rawValue {
        case "good":
            self = .good
        case "bad":
            self = .bad
        default:
            self = .other(rawValue)
        }
    }
    
    var description: String {
        rawValue
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make this a fair bit shorter/tidier by pairing up the `case` and `return` statements together on the same line, like `case .good: return "good"`

Comment: @Sweeper but I still need to `print(StatusA.good.rawValue)` to get the value `good`?

Comment: @jacobcan118 no, by conforming to `CustomStringConvertible`, `print` will output the `description` property. Did you try the code?